# multiple chi-squared tests for concluding divergence over representation in a group

Tags: python, chi-squared-test, fishers-exact-test

I try to distinguish under which group a specific instance is over-represented, if any. My data has 3 groups (columns), and 150+ instances (rows), and the values are counts each instance is present in a group. I would like to perform a chi-squared test for each row to conclude if an instance is over-represented (i.e., greater prevalence than others) in a specific group, and which group.

First, I wonder whether this is the right test for such question. Another natural option is Fisher exact t-test. Which one is better for such case?

Second, From looking at coding examples, I didn't manage to run the test for each row, but only for the entire dataset (as a contingency table) which made me think I may be missing something.

An example of the data I use:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100,(10,3)), columns=['g1', 'g2', 'g3'])
df.index = ['var' + str(i+1) for i in range(len(df.index))]

df.head(5)
Out[12]: 
      g1  g2  g3
var1  23  24  18
var2  88  15  70
var3  24  42  86
var4  39  55  62
var5  62  86  59
```

The final aim is to determine for each instance (row), whether it is over-represented, with respect to the statistical test, and significance. Something like this:

```
      g1  g2  g3 final_score
var1  23  24  18 NA
var2  88  15  70 g1
var3  24  42  86 g3
var4  39  55  62 NA
var5  62  86  59 g2
```

The final_score column indicate whether a variable is at all over-represented or not (NA for insignificant results), and for which group it is if so.

Any help regarding this would be much appreciated!